# How to hide/ignore task in Flower Dashboard for Celery?

Tags: python, celery, flower

### Context

I used this tutorial to create a rate limit for my celery tasks that works over multiple Queues/Workers.
https://alievmagomed.com/celery-throttling-setting-rate-limit-for-queues/

It uses the concept of a Token Bucket. A function creates tokens in a queue in a specified interval. The actual task can not run if there is no token available in the bucket. Pretty cool!

Here is the task that creates the tokens:

```
@celery.task
def token():
    return 1

@celery.on_after_configure.connect
def setup_periodic_tasks(sender, **kwargs):
    # generating auto issuing of tokens for all lmited groups
    for name, limit in rate_limits.items():
        sender.add_periodic_task(60 / limit, token.signature(queue=name+'_tokens'))
```

### Problem

I also use Flower to monitor Celery tasks. The problem is that the tasks that is creating the tokens is polluting the whole dashboard. If for instance I have one queue that can handle 120 tasks a minute I will also see 120 completed token tasks in my dashboard.

### Question

Is it possible to ignore one specific task in flower? I have searched the docs and tried to manipulate the task with `format_task` in `flowerconfig.py`. But without success so far.

Answer (score 0):

So you can easily hide a task form with `send_events=False`:

```
@celery.task(send_events=False, name="rate_limit_token")
def token():
    return 1
```